# How to use routeHelperProvider for ui-router in style guide John Papa

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone help me finding the right way to use routing method using `routerHelperProvider` with [john papa style guide](http://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#routing), because I tried doing it but I got an error like the following and I don't know why.

```
 [Error: Could not resolve 'hello' from state '']

w/z.transitionTo@http://localhost:443/belajar-angularJSLagi/mastering/app/_lib/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:17`
w/z.go@http://localhost:443/belajar-angularJSLagi/mastering/app/_lib/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:16936
```